# Excel: Sort column by specific names, than add the sum of the sorted items to separated cell

Tags: excel, sum

I have a column where I am going to add 3 specific strings `("zero","one","two")`.

These items will be sorted by default. I want a separated cell for the "zero" to search how many "zero" are there in the column and calculate the sum of them.

The problem is that every time when I use this document, the amount of "zero"-es will be different.

Comment: Use `Countif()` formula.

Comment: and `sumif()` for the sum

Comment: or use a Pivot Table

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood your question is that you have a column with Multi names (Zero, One and Two) with a corresponding value cell and you want add the values of all the Zeros. Well as by this, the Sumif() function will help you good. See the picture at Following. see in the formula bar

[image: Sumif() function]

and use Countif() to count the Zeros in the Column.

[image]